# Change REPLACE SQL function in PHP to remove a contact

Tags: php, mysql, email, pdo

I recently cleaned up my web app's code. My web app is a simple social network with Add,Remove,etc procedures. I have a php file which I call when a user want to remove a contact from his friend list.

I came up with a strange bug in my application that I haven't estimate the time I wrote it.

### The Bug

Let's say we have two friend emails in our list.

1. georgeMARK@email.com
2. MARK@email.com

The contact emails are stored in a MYSQL DB column with name `Contacts` and every email is separated by a semicolon (`;`) symbol. So our example's column will look like this (depend on which user has added lastly it can be vice versa):

```
georgeMARK@email.com;MARK@email.com;
```

So assume that our user wants to remove `MARK` from his contacts. He presses the button and ... both email's have gone.!

Have a look in my PHPMyAdmin Panel I found that what has left from the column is this:

```
george
```

The problem is in my PDO SQL statement that I use to remove accounts from my column.

```
$STH = $DHB->prepare("UPDATE `Users` SET `Contacts` = REPLACE(`Contacts`, :email, '') WHERE `UserEmail` = :my_email");
```

The `REPLACE` function just replaces all the instances of the `:email` and thats awful. I use the same approach many times in my application and I understand that this will cause my the same bug to appear elsewhere too.

My question is how can I delete a user's email without affecting the others 'instances'? Do I have to change my point of view and how what do I need to do?

Comment: Why don't you create a separate table with rows for each email address?

Comment: @Ties Good point but again I have to connect somewhat the user with the emails so in the end I'll get the same result.

Comment: If you have a separate table you can use `DELETE WHERE email=:email` and because every email is in another row it will only remove on real match

Comment: @Ties yeap I know but lets say I have to read the contacts of the user. I'll need another column that with connect the users each with each others and if one person has many  friends how many column do I need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fast *dirty* way is to prepend a semicolon to all Contacts field, so that entries as like this:

```
;georgeMARK@email.com;MARK@email.com;
```

then you can replace it in this way:

```
$emailToDelete = ";$emailToDelete;"
... REPLACE(`Contacts`, :email, ';') ...
```

A better approach can be to store contacts data in a more suitable format (like JSON).

The best solution is to create a relationships table and delete all the entries relative to contact to delete.

Comment: I thank you for your laziness !!!! :) -I'll update my db structure in the upcoming revisions.

Answer (score 0):

### Structure

Maybe create a structure like this:

Table Users

```
id | Name | Email
-----------------
1  | John | john@example.com
2  | Jane | jane@example2.com
```

Table Friendships

```
User1_id | User2_id
-------------------
1        | 2
```

---

### Select users

```
SELECT * FROM Users WHERE name=:name
```

### Select friends

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    Friendships
LEFT JOIN
    Users
ON
    Friendships.User1_id = Users.id
WHERE 
    User1_id=:user_id
```

### Delete friendship

```
DELETE FROM Friendships WHERE User1_id=:current_user_id AND User2_id=:friend_to_remove_id
```

Comment: the emails domain are all the same.

Comment: that doesn't matter, they can be anything you like

Comment: @GeorgeGkas do you understand my example?

Comment: I'm not an database administarator. (Not yet at least) If you can provide examples from the web of your structure then you would helped me enough.

Comment: Do you have access to the database? Can you create tables?

Comment: And how do you currently select users and friends?